# How to find IP address to connect in AWS data warehouse

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, networking, ip, warehouse

I need to connect data warehouse on AWS but the administrator asked me this:

"IP address that you're going to connect to the data warehouse from?"

Which IP he is referring to, is it my router's IP? Or the internet company they generate?

How do I find out which IP he is talking about?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a private networks connecting to somewhere on the same private network then it would be the IP address of your computer.

If you're going over the internet from a private network you will most likely traverse a Network Address Translation (NAT) proxy. It will have a public ip address assigned from your ISP. You can find out that IP address by visiting one of several services or Google "what's my ip" and it will tell you your public facing NAT address.

Be careful that an external NAT address may change over time.